# How to Transparent ViewController to See Parent

Tags: objective-c, viewcontroller

I would like to present view controller with transparent to see parent below

```
// RootViewController.m    
SecondViewController *svc = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController: svc animated: YES completion:nil];
```

My SecondViewController was called and start-up with transparent for only 1sec and then become black no transparent even though I have tried code below:

```
// SecondViewController.m
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[self.view setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 51 green: 51 blue:51 alpha: 0.5]];
```

But it doesn't help, it still transparent for the time in 1sec and then no transparent anymore.

How to transparent ViewController to see parent?

Thank for reading.

Comment: Are you presenting `SecondViewController` on iPad?  I think presenting a transparent viewController is a little wired in visual effect .

Comment: I am presenting SecondViewController in iPhone.

Comment: I prefer to us a customized container view controller to achieve this, system presenting view controller with some wrapper view and you don't want to set it's transparent. See [Container View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6)